# MySQL join to fetch user information

Tags: mysql, join

I have table A with 2 different user IDs(Originator and Assigned_To) in it and

a separate table B  with IDs, First Name , Last Name etc..

TABLE A ( ISSUE)

```
  Ticket | Originator | Assigned_To
  TKT1234  abc452       kshd736
  TKT1235  abc453       kshd738
  TKT1236  abc454       kshd739
```

TABLE B (  User Table )

```
  User ID | First Name | Last Name 
  abc452     John        Smith
  kshd736    Mary          J
  abc453     A           Sharma
  kshd738   Brad         Smith
```

Required Result Table :

```
  Ticket | Originator Name    | Assigned_To_Name 
  TKT1234  John Smith(abc452)    Mary J(kshd736)
  TKT1235  A Sharma(abc453)      Brad Smith(kshd738)
  ....
  ....
```

How can I join these two tables in order to get a combined ( Name + ID ) field.
I tried something below but this isn't it :

```
   (select  ticket_id,
concat(e.first_name,e.last_name, " (", a.originator, ")")  as originator , 
  concat(e.first_name,e.last_name, " (", a.issue_assigned_to, ")")  as 
 assigned_to 
 FROM ISSUE a
 LEFT JOIN DPDM_ISSUE_REVISION_RELATIONSHIP b ON a.name = b.issue
   LEFT JOIN DPDM_REVISION c ON b.reported_against_revision = c.name
   LEFT JOIN DPDM_MASTER d ON c.master = d.name
    left join USER e on a.originator = e.user_id 
 where a.lifecycle_state not in ("Closed") and ( c.name like '%HVBMS%' OR c.name like '%BCC6%'));
```

Can someone guide in this ? Thanks !

Comment: Help us help you - please share the table structures, some sample data, and the result you'd like to get for that sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query seems some random SQL related to the question you ask. I assume you want to do something like this:

```
SELECT a.ticket, 
  CONCAT(b.first_name, " ", b.last_name, " (", a.originator,")") as originator_name, 
  CONCAT(c.first_name, " ", c.last_name, " (", a.assigned_to,")") as assigned_to_name
FROM ISSUE a
LEFT JOIN USER b ON a.originator = b.user_id
LEFT JOIN USER c ON a.assigned_to = c.user_id
```

Hope this helps.